# Python face-recognition package with pickled data

Tags: python, pickle, face-recognition

How can I integrate pickled face_data.dat to python face-recognition default example which shows real-time webcam view?

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np



# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Load a sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
obama_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
obama_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(obama_image)[0]

# Load a second sample picture and learn how to recognize it.
biden_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("biden.jpg")
biden_face_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(biden_image)[0]

# Create arrays of known face encodings and their names
known_face_encodings = [
    obama_face_encoding,
    biden_face_encoding
]
known_face_names = [
    "Barack Obama",
    "Joe Biden"
]

while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Find all the faces and face enqcodings in the frame of video
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    # Loop through each face in this frame of video
    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
        # if True in matches:
        #     first_match_index = matches.index(True)
        #     name = known_face_names[first_match_index]

        # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
        face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(known_face_encodings, face_encoding)
        best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
        if matches[best_match_index]:
            name = known_face_names[best_match_index]

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've pickled the images and tried modifying the program as follows but It's showing the wrong names.

```
import face_recognition
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pickle



# Get a reference to webcam #0 (the default one)
video_capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)



# Load face encodings
with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'rb') as f:
    all_face_encodings = pickle.load(f)

# Grab the list of names and the list of encodings
face_names = list(all_face_encodings.keys())
face_encodings = np.array(list(all_face_encodings.values()))




while True:
    # Grab a single frame of video
    ret, frame = video_capture.read()

    # Convert the image from BGR color (which OpenCV uses) to RGB color (which face_recognition uses)
    rgb_frame = frame[:, :, ::-1]

    # Find all the faces and face enqcodings in the frame of video
    face_locations = face_recognition.face_locations(rgb_frame)
    face_encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(rgb_frame, face_locations)

    # Loop through each face in this frame of video
    for (top, right, bottom, left), face_encoding in zip(face_locations, face_encodings):
        # See if the face is a match for the known face(s)
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(face_encodings, face_encoding)

        name = "Unknown"

        # If a match was found in known_face_encodings, just use the first one.
        if True in matches:
            first_match_index = matches.index(True)
            name = face_names[first_match_index]

        # Or instead, use the known face with the smallest distance to the new face
#         face_distances = face_recognition.face_distance(face_encodings, face_encoding)
#         best_match_index = np.argmin(face_distances)
#         if matches[best_match_index]:
#             name = face_names[best_match_index]

        # Draw a box around the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # Draw a label with a name below the face
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, bottom - 35), (right, bottom), (0, 0, 255), cv2.FILLED)
        font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left + 6, bottom - 6), font, 1.0, (255, 255, 255), 1)

    # Display the resulting image
    cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

    # Hit 'q' on the keyboard to quit!
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# Release handle to the webcam
video_capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I've checked pickled data using this script. It is showing the correct output to the relevant image.

```
import face_recognition
import pickle
import numpy as np

# Load face encodings
with open('dataset_faces.dat', 'rb') as f:
    all_face_encodings = pickle.load(f)

# Grab the list of names and the list of encodings
face_names = list(all_face_encodings.keys())

face_encodings = np.array(list(all_face_encodings.values()))

# Try comparing an unknown image
unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file("obama.jpg")
unknown_face = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)
result = face_recognition.compare_faces(face_encodings, unknown_face)

# Print the result as a list of names with True/False
names_with_result = list(zip(face_names, result))
print(names_with_result)
```

Comment: Can you please reduce your code to the lines that give unexpected behavior? What exactly is wrong with the names? What is your output, and what would you expect? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: As an example, It shows "Obama" instead of "Putin" when using pickled data. I don't know which part is incorrect that's why I added the whole code.